# C char array concatenation

Tags: c, arrays, char, concatenation

What I have:

```
char cmd[50] = "some text here";
char v[] = {'a','s','d','c','b'};
```

So I want to concatenate `cmd` by adding a letter from `v`.

Obviously:

```
strcat(cmd, v[3]);
```

doesn't work because `strcat` doesn't accept the `v[n]` parameter `n = int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problems with your approach.

- C strings must end in 0 byte, in other words `'\0'` character. Using `""` adds that automatically, but otherwise you have to add it yourself, and all string functions depend on that 0 being there.
- Your v array contains characters, not strings, and `strcat` takes strings.

One solution:

```
char cmd[50] = "some text here";
char *v[] = {"a","s","d","c","b"};
strcat(cmd,v[3]);
```

This turns your char array into array of pointers to C strings.

Also, it's your responsibility to take care that, `cmd[]` contains enough space to hold whatever you add to it with strcat (here it does). It's usually best to use `snprintf` to do string concatenation, as it takes total size of the target array *including* terminating null, and adds that null there always, so it's harder to mess up. Example with your original char array:

```
char cmd[50] = "some text here";
char buf[50];
char v[] = {'a','s','d','c','b'};
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%c", cmd, v[3]);
```

Notes: sizeof like this works only when `buf` really is an array, declared with `[]` like here. Also with snprintf, using same buffer both as destination and format argument may yield unexpected results, so I added a new destination buffer variable.

One more snprintf example, with your original two arrays only, appending to end of current contents of cmd:

```
snprintf(cmd + strlen(cmd), (sizeof cmd) - strlen(cmd), "%c", v[3]);
```

So clearly, in this particular case, the `strncat(cmd, &v[3], 1)` suggested in other answers to add 1 character is much nicer, but benefit of snprintf is, you can add all datatype supported by printf, not chars.

Comment: Thank you! If I can take care that cmd[] contains enough space, which one you think is the FASTEST method?

Comment: strncat is probably the fastest of these, but fastest is `int len=strlen(cmd); cmd[len] = v[3]; cmd[len+1] = 0;`. Note how array indexing starts from 0, so `some_cstring[strlen(some_cstring)]` is always 0.

Comment: Unexpected in-depth answer - thanks for providing value!

Answer (score 12):

Hmm. As far as I understand you want to add a single char from the second array?
so you have to use

```
  strncat (cmd, &v[3], 1);
```

:-)

Comment: I chose another way to do it but this also works ad it's very simple. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Do ***not*** use this:

```
strcat(cmd,&v[3]);
```

`&v[3]` is not a pointer to a null terminated string! instead use

```
strncat(cmd, &v[3], 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure the variable 'cmd' has enough memory allocated.

Second, the mention to 'v[3]' is the value which is a signed byte. You have to use the following call to strncat (not strcat):

```
strncat(cmd,&v[3],1);
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
strcat(cmd,&v[3]);
```

Comment: This will add more than one char, and it'll look beyond the end of the array to be copied from since there's no null termination.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you don't use strcat as well:

```
char *strcat (char *dest, const char *src);
```

because you do

```
char *strcat (char *dest, char src);
```

So you must declared a char * as your char.

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[2];

sprintf(buf,"%c", V[3]);
strcat(cmd, buf);
```

or

```
strncat (cmd, &v[3],1);
```

you can not do it with

```
strcat(cmd,&v[3]);
```

this will coppy the V array from cell 3 to the end of array and not copy only V[3]

I can suggest another solution

```
int len = strlen(cmd);
cmd[len]=v[3];
cmd[len+1] = '\0';
```